# Access Kubernetes Pod logs with Fluentd

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, fluentd

I have an pod in the **eks ** cluster that has application logs in multiple locations (ex: `/opt/tomcat/logs/*.logs` and `/var/log/*.logs`) within the pod. I want to move these logs to Amazon CloudWatch using the Fluentd.

These logs are not part of container logs and are not present in `/var/log/containers/*.log`. Also, I am unable to access these logs using the kubectl commands. So using Fluentd, I am unable to ship these to CloudWatch.

Can someone please suggest how I can access these logs from the worker node and ship them to CloudWatch? Or is there any way that we can ship the logs from the pod to WorkerNode or CloudWatch?

Comment: Try fluentbit btw

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the **multiple paths** to get the **logs** and push them to Cloudwatch. Also, you can set the **multiple filters** as per need.

`path /var/logs/*.log,/var/logs/dir1/*.log,/var/logs/dir2/*.log`

Example config

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_fos_logs
  @label @LOGS
  path /var/logs/*.log,/var/logs/dir1/*.log,/var/logs/dir2/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/logs.log.pos
  time_format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z"
  read_from_head true
  tag "rowlogs.*"
  format none
</source>
```